# Android ICS, Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My android app has one background service. I observed that this service is restarting and not showing any exception in debug log also.

I taken more interest to identify the problem with my app and finally found one special message **Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...** in debug log.

After this message appears, I saw message as my service created and printing all debug messages of my application as when we launch first time.

My app's ,manifest file has `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />`

and i am using Android 4.0 Samsung Galaxy S Duos mobile phone to test my app.

Can anybody please suggest the solution or what is the exact problem with my app.

Or please tell me if anything I missed in my app's manifest, because I am new to Android 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

The "Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8" message is not a bug, it's just the system informing you that it is turning on some compatibility features due to the fact that your device is running Android 4+ while the code is compiled for an older version (API level 8).

So whatever causes your problem is not this logcat line!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your Manifest's string

```
<uses-sdk         
    android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

to

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

And don't forget to download 14 SDK version.

Comment: If I use target SDK version 14, will my app works on lower versions ?

Comment: I think it won't work correct (if does). If you need lower APIs and can't refuse using them, you'd better just ignore this warning or create 2 different versions for higher and lower APIs.